# Can not select .NET Frameworks above 4.8

Tags: frameworks

Hey I tried to install the latest .NET Framework 6.0.1 from the official Microsoft Website and it shows as installed inside the Visual Studio Installer but I am somehow not able to select it. Neither can I upgrade existing Applications to 6.0 nor create Applications with .NET Framework 6.0.

So i tried installing .NET Framework 5.0 instead but it has the excatly same issues.

The highest Version that I can choose is .NET Framework 4.8.

In case it is important I am on Windows 10 - 21H1 - 19044.1415.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xr1LI.jpg)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yO2Qo.jpg)

[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBRWm.jpg)

Comment: There is no such thing as .NET Framework 5.0, nor is there .NET Framework 6.0.1. The final release of .NET Framework was 4.8. ".NET Core" has been renamed to simply ".NET" and following on from version 3.1, we now have .NET 5, and .NET 6.

Answer (score 0):

Last version of .NET Framework is 4.8. Last version of .NET is .NET 6. They are not the same thing, .NET is a successor of .NET Core.